# JavaScript not working with Chrome & Xampp!

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, xampp

I've been trying for a couple hours now to figure out why JavaScript wouldn't work.
The code works, but here it is anyway.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(text)
{
document.f1.ta.value="Hi!";
}
</script>
<form name="f1">
<input type="textarea" id="ta"/>
<input type="button" action='change("Hi!")'/>
</form>
```

When I click the button, it does nothing.
When I write "document.f1.ta.value="Hi!";" in the Chrome's inspector console, it works.
I am using XAMPP (for Windows) 1.7.3 Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is using "action" - that should be "onclick" for an element itself..

and/or

document.f1.ta.value="Hi!"; is failing... try

```
function test() {
   alert('test');
}
```

and add

```
<button onclick="test();">Test</button>
```

to your body

Comment: Oh, it was you, not CMS. Thanks, though! :D

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

You have specified an `action` attribute on the button, I think you are looking for the `onclick` intrinsic event:

```
<input type="button" onclick='change("Hi!")'/>
```

The standard way *(DOM0)* to access forms and form elements would be:

```
function change(text) {
  document.forms[0].elements.ta.value = text;
}
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/uxejo/3/).

Comment: Thank you very much! The onclick worked. I did not need to do "forms["*"]" and elements. Thanks a lot, though!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a standard way of accessing elements.  Use [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) or [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).

```
document.getElementById("ta").value="Hi!";
```

As noted by CMS, you also want `onclick` for the button.

Comment: I tried that way, but it did not work. It does now though, thanks to CMS. (:

Comment: @Anon, `getElementById` should work.  Did you also correct the `onclick`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. It worked after I did the onclick that CMS suggested. :P